# How can I collapse/expand a datePicker() from compact to graphical, like the calendar app?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, calendar, swiftui-list

I've been trying to achieve the calendar select date UI however the default datePicker() is just a line with some sort of bubble that shows up to select a date and disappears once selected. [this is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S52MC.png), I've been looking for answers all over stack overflow I found one very similar one, however the answers are too complicated with code that I don't honestly understand.

this is my code snippet which is embedded in a list:

```
 Section(header: CustomText("Schedule Time")){
                            DatePicker("Select Date", selection: $wakeUp, in: Date()...)
                                .background(.white)
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                                .accentColor(.purple)
```

[this is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3NF3.png) if there's anyone who knows a simplified way of achieving this interface please share, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is the default behaviour of a system date picker that displays a floating component on activation. On calendar app it's more of an inline style expanding date picker. To achieve this you will need to make use of a state variable and show a date picker as a graphical component on activation. Check the example below.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var date: Date = Date()
    @State var showDatePicker = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Date -> format your selected date as desired") {
                showDatePicker.toggle()
            }
            
            if showDatePicker {
                DatePicker("Date", selection: $date, displayedComponents: .date)
                    .datePickerStyle(.graphical)
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help. If the code snippet / response above was what you were looking for, please help to mark it as the answer. That'll help anyone else that might stumble on to this post in future.  Thank you